# Can Hibernate unwrap lead to unexpected behaviour?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to execute plain SQL query inside an ejb 3 service method (for example I need to get data from some technical oracle tables or execute stored procedure and so on), my strategy was the following:

Get a plain jdbc connection

```
private Connection getConnection() {
      org.hibernate.Session hibernateSession =   entityManager.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
  final Connection[] connections = new Connection[1];
  hibernateSession.doWork(connection -> connections[0] = connection);
  return connections[0];
}
```

use the connection:

```
public String doStuff() throws MyException{
SomeKindOfManagedObject o = new SomeKindOfManagedObject()
entityManager.persist(o)

//business logic
//modification to object "o"

final Connection connection = getConnection();
String query = "select * from all_tab_partitions where table_name = '"+ MY_TABLE +"'";
try (final Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
      final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
      doSomeKindOfStuff(rs);
}catch(Exception e){
      logger.log(e);
      throw new MyException(e);
}

entityManager.merge(o);

}
```

are there some kind of potential hidden issues related to unwrapping and using a plain jdbc connection as I did? Specifically bounded to transaction managment?

Is it a problem to mix ORM operation and plain JDBC query as I did?

I've noticed that, in some case, after DDL/DML operations a call to em.merge(object) produce a

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context):
```

Why such a behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there should not be any 'hidden' issues. However, don't forget to close the statements, result sets and any other closable resources which you manually opened.

Regardless of that, you should favor using native queries ([`entityManager.createNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-)) over direct `Connection` manipulation (to avoid the need to manually manage the lifecycle of connection resources, to stay within JPA, etc).

Regarding the error you receive sometimes after **DDL**/DML operations, most databases [implicitly commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html) the active transaction before and after any DDL operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like, as you said, that the ddl operation commit and close the transaction and the result is that the following operation generate the TransactionRequiredException.  I will move to a "createNativeQuery" approach. Thank you!